# How to center a div on multiple devices

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div which contains some anchor tags which contains an image. Is there a way by which i can center the div in multiple devices no matter what the width of devices is?

Here is the code:

```
 <div class="jaffa">
       <a href="#">
         <img src="" >
         <span>sample text</span></a>
       <a href="#">
         <img src="" >
         <span>sample text</span></a>
       <a href="#">
         <img src="" >
         <span>sample text</span></a>
     </div>
```

Each anchor tag has a fixed width and height and depending on width of screen some times 2 anchor tags display in a row and sometimes 3.

Here is my css:

```
 @media(max-width:480){
  .jaffa a{
  width:200px;
  height:90px;
  padding:20px;
  }
  @media(min-width:481){
  .jaffa a{
  width:140px;
  height:90px;
  padding:20px;
  }
```

Comment: You're only about the thousand person to ask this question here... The "in multiple devices" twist doesn't change anything to the solution.

Comment: oh !! i am sorry for that could not find any answer after a lot of google search.and can u please link any previously answered question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if position static (default) you have to use `margin:0 auto;` else use `left:50%;  margin-left:-(half of the width of your div)`

Answer (score 0):

try this `img {margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;}` This will center the image exactly in the middle of the container no matter the width is.

If you face any problems with the height you can also try:

```
margin-top:auto; margin-bottom: auto;
```